# OData grammar error

Tags: bug, data-explorer, status-completed

On http://odata.stackexchange.com/faq

The FAQ reads:

> How to I name and describe my queries

Perhaps it should read:

> How **do** I name and describe my queries? `<-- question mark & do`

Also:

> What is the deal with magic columns

...lacks a question mark.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this, will sort it out with the next push

Comment: should be sorted now, keep the reports coming :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

fixed a while back ... vote me up so I bump out of the unanswered list